# Пометка всех строк, выводимых в таблице

Tags: access, delphi

У меня вот такая проблемка...В таблице Заказ у меня выводятся блюда, которые заказал посетитель. Мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии кнопки, все строки, выведенные в этой таблице (отбор выведенных строк уже ведется по номеру столика), ставилось значение true в логическом поле БД Access.
Пыталась реализовать следующим образом:

```
procedure TForm6.BitBtn10Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.first;
while not dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.eof do
begin
ADOQuery3.Edit;
ADOQuery3['Oplata']:=True;
ADOQuery3.Post;
dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.next;
end;
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='Select NStolika,Bludo, Kolichestvo,Price,DateZakaza,Oplata from ZakazIzMenu where Oplata=False and nstolika=:m';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.Parambyname('m').Value:=strtoint(Label4.Caption);
ADOQuery1.Open;
Form9.ADOQuery1.Close;
Form9.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form9.ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM zakazizmenu WHERE nstolika=:m';
Form9.ADOQuery1.Parameters.Parambyname('m').Value:=strtoint(Label4.Caption);
Form9.ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Но в этом случае отмечается только одна строка, хотя произвожу перебор строк... Помогите разобраться

Comment: @teanЫЧ,

    dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.first; while not dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.eof do begin ADOQuery1.Close;         
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='UPDATE ZakazIzMenu set Oplata = true WHERE nstolika=:m ';     
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.Parambyname('m').Value:=strtoint(Label4.Caption);
    ADOQuery1.ExecSQL; ADOQuery1.Open; dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.next; end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно, вы перелистываете один объект, а работаете со значениями другого. Попробуйте так:

```
ADOQuery3.First;
while not ADOQuery3.eof do // тут пишу по памяти. синтаксис не помню
begin
ADOQuery3.Edit;
ADOQuery3['Oplata']:=True;
ADOQuery3.Post;
ADOQuery3.next;
end;
```

---

Тогда просматривайте все ваши записи, как раньше. Только изменение по-другому делайте, например:

```
dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.first;
while not dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.eof do
begin
  ADOQueryX.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQueryX.SQL.Add('UPDATE ZakazIzMenu set Oplata = true WHERE NStolika = '+ dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.FieldByName('NStolika').asString);
  ADOQueryX.ExecSQL;
  dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.next;
end;
```

Как-то так...

Comment: @teanЫЧ, сработало, но отметились все объекты из бд, а нужно, чтобы отметились только те, что выведены по условию в таблицу.
Просто условие, по которому выводятся записи, у меня закреплено не в sql запросе в ADOQuery. Видимо поэтому не срабатывает. А закрепить его там я не могу

Comment: @Анна_Мазурова, что значит закреплено?

Comment: @maxleo, я имела ввиду, что выборка по столику содержится не в в sql запросе в ADOQuery, а в самом программном коде.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, попробовала так как вы написали, не сработала. Изменила код вот так

    dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.first;
    while not dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.eof do
    begin
      ADOQuery1.Close;
      ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='UPDATE ZakazIzMenu set Oplata = true WHERE nstolika=:m ';
      ADOQuery1.Parameters.Parambyname('m').Value:=strtoint(Label4.Caption);
      ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
      ADOQuery1.Open;
      dbgrid1.datasource.dataset.next;
    end;

Comment: Выдает ошибку и пишет следующее:"First chance exception at $758BB760. Exception class EOleException with message 'Текущий поставщик не поддерживает возврат нескольких наборов записей в результате выполнения одной операции'. Process Project2.exe (6408)"

Comment: код покажите

Comment: @Анна_Мазурова, у вас зачем там Open после ExecSQL?